# Optimal solution to output a list of integers from a number of type string

Tags: python, string, list, int

I want to get a list of integers from a number of type string.

Input:

```
s="1234"
```

Expected Output:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

---

```
    s="1234"
    inp=[]
    for e in int(s):
        inp.append(e)
    print (inp)
```

I get the following error
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

So i did this:

```
    s="1234"
    inp=[]
    for e in s:
        inp.append(int(e))
    print (inp)
```

I get the output i needed but is there a better way to do it

Comment: What makes you think it's suboptimal? Is there actually some *problem* with your implementation? Aside from making it a list comprehension, which you can look up how to do, that's probably as good as you're going to get.

Comment: Why not just use list comprehension? You have a string `s` and you need a list of integers. Easy one liner is `result = [int(c) for c in s]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in one line using a neat piece of syntax called a "list comprehension":

```
>>> s = "1234"
>>> [int(i) for i in s]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

Using a list comprehension would generally be considered more Pythonic as what is going on is clearer. In addition, although your solution is in-theory doing the same operations, this solution will run very *slightly* faster (especially with longer strings) as there is no overhead of calling `append` and looking up the list in memory. However, this performance difference is negligible and you should go with what suits you best.

Comment: Please use inline code formatting only for actual code, e.g. references to types, methods or identifiers.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sure, I will in the future :)

Answer (score 4):

A very simple, short, one liner solution:

```
>>> list(map(int, "1234"))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

On Python 2 you can drop the `list` call.

Comment: Note that this will have a different output in Python 3.x. Also that list call is redundant, strings are already iterable by character.

Comment: @jonrsharpe "*Note that this will have a different output in Python 3.x*" – not any more

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
some_string = '12345'
integers = [int(i) for i in some_string]
```

Which `integers` would have the value:
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

This would not be better than your solution but another way of doing it.

Comment: It's shorter and faster. What makes you say it wouldn't be better?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Depends on better for what? It's faster, you are right. By the other hand it needs additional space. Also, for a beginner would you start explaining with a list comprehension solution or an iterative one (which normally are easier to understand)?

Comment: What additional space?